# If $a^{\frac {1}{x}}= b^{\frac {1}{y}}=c^{\frac {1}{z}}$ and $a$, $b$, $c$ are in AP then $x$, $y$, $z$ are in

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

If $a^{\frac {1}{x}}= b^{\frac {1}{y}}=c^{\frac {1}{z}}$ and $a$, $b$, $c$ are in AP then $x$, $y$, $z$ are in

$a$. A.P

$b$. G.P

$c$. H.P

$d$. None.

My Attempt:
$a$, $b$, $c$ are in AP
$$\dfrac {a+c}{2}=b$$
$$a+c=2b.$$
Now,
$$a^{\dfrac {1}{x}}=b^{\dfrac {1}{y}}$$
$$a^{\dfrac {y}{x}}=b$$
$$2a^{\dfrac {y}{x}}=2b$$
$$2a^{\dfrac {y}{x}}=a+c$$

How do I proceed?

Comment: Hint: try a few special cases. $a=1,b=2,c=3$ and $x=1$ is a good starting point : what are $y$ and $z$?

Comment: $a=2,b=4,c=6,x=1$ is another informative one.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Your first example is not a good one because there is no solution for $y$ or $z$ in the reals, so the initial condition cannot be met. Your second example is a much better one as $x = 1, y = 2$ but $z$ can be proven to be irrational because of prime factorisation, so $x,y,z$ can't be in H.P. (A.P and G.P. can be obviously ruled out).

Comment: I think the question should be like: If $a,b,c$ are in G.P. ...

Comment: @k.Vijay, You mean to say that instead of $a$, $b$, $c$ are in AP it should be $a$, $b$, $c$ are in GP??

Comment: Yes, there is a typo in your question

Comment: The correct choice is (b) G.P

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your question. It should be "If $a, b, c$ are in G.P. and $a^{1 / x}=b^{1 / y}=c^{1 / t}$, then show that $x, y, z$ are in A.P."

Let $a^{1 / x}=b^{1 / y}=c^{1 / 4}=k$.
Then, $a=k^{x}, b=h^{y}$ and $c=k^{z}$.
Now, $a, b, c$ are in G.P. $\Rightarrow b^{2}=a c$
$$
\begin{aligned} \Rightarrow\left(k^{y}\right)^{2}=k^{x}, h^{2}=h^{x+2} \\ & \Rightarrow k^{2 y}=k^{x+z} \\ & \Rightarrow 2 y=(x+z) . \end{aligned}
$$
This shows that $x, y, z$ are in A.P.